# Why does rpart not produce a perfect prediction when forced to?

Tags: r, cart, rpart

I am trying to understand rpart all the details in rpart package. I am aware of the complexity parameter `cp`, which prevents a split if the *improvement* is less than `cp`

If I set `minbucket = 1`, `minsplit = 1` and `cp = -Inf` (or `cp = 0`) the tree should be allowed to grow to perfectly fit the data; provided that all the values of the predictor, or combination of predictors, are different. But it does not.

There must be another parameter which is preventing some splits to be made since, as you can see in this image, data is not fitted perfectly. One can clearly see there are some leaves which have more than one element, as we see them *layered* in the lower part.

[image]

This is a MVE illustrating this issue, and generating the image above:

```
set.seed(1)
sample_size <- 1000
y <- rgamma(sample_size, shape = 2, rate = 0.75)
x <- rgamma(sample_size, shape = 0.5, rate = 2)

library(rpart)
md <- rpart(formula = y ~ x, data = data.frame(y,x), method = "anova", cp = -Inf, minbucket = 1, minsplit = 1)

# All elements in x are unique:
length(unique(x)) == sample_size

#Number of leaves with more than one element:
sum(md$frame[md$frame$var == "<leaf>", "n"] > 1)

#Scatterplot
plot(y, predict(md, newdata = data.frame(x)), xlab = "Observed", ylab = "Predicted", 
     col = scales::alpha("black", 0.2), pch = 16)
```

**Note:** For debugging purposes note that using `sample_size = 185` already produces a leaf with 2 values.

Comment: Changing the sample size from `1000` to `185` already yields one leaf with more than one observation. A smaller MWE might make analysis easier.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Great suggestion, I have added a note. I have left the original value since the scatterplot is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for posting an erroneous answer in a former attempt to help (now deleted). This post explains how to calculate the depth of a tree:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900725/6503141

So if you run the code in the question and after that the following

```
nodes <- as.numeric(rownames(md$frame))
max(rpart:::tree.depth(nodes))
```

You will find that you have reached the `maxdepth = 30` limit described in `help(rpart.control)` as

> Set the maximum depth of any node of the final tree, with the root node counted as depth 0. Values greater than 30 rpart will give nonsense results on 32-bit machines.

On my 64-bit Windows machine (R version 4.0.2, rpart version 4.1-15) setting `maxdepth` to anything larger then 30 leads to an error message.
With `set.seed(1); sample_size <- 185` you also reach `maxdepth == 30` but not with `set.seed(1); sample_size <- 184`. This makes `maxdepth` the a likely candidate for the parameter you search. Unfortunately there seems to be no obvious way to increase it.

Comment: Seems like we have a smoking gun. I will do some tests to confirm this. Thanks a lot.